# Pytest getting test results and uploading if the test passed or failed to Jira

Tags: python, jira

Hi I'm trying to upload if a test passed or failed to Jira. So I have my test

```
@pytest.mark.jira('ORK-922') #Jira issue key
def test_hello_pytest(self):
    assert(True)
```

But I'm having trouble finding a suitable way to get the test results in a JSON format that Jira understands. How can I format the result so Jira will accept my API call?